# Путь HTML файла в JS скрипте

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется такой вопрос.

Есть некий скрипт, который несет в себе путь к `html` документу, чтобы он работал, они должны находится в одном файле,

***Путь к скрипту:*** `Desktop\К\uploader>node app.js`

***Путь к доку:***    `Desktop\К\index.html`

При смене пути выдает такую ошибку ***`на тот момент путь к файлу был указан:`*** `..\index.html`:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'C:\Users\profr\Desktop\К\uploader..\index.html'

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var upload = require('express-fileupload');
const http = require('http');
http.Server(app).listen(2000);
app.use(upload());

console.log("Server Started at port 2000");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '../index.html');
})
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  if (req.files.upfile) {
    var file = req.files.upfile,
      name = file.name,
      type = file.mimetype;
    var uploadpath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + name;
    file.mv(uploadpath, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("File Upload Failed", name, err);
        res.send("Error Occured!")
      } else {
        console.log("File Uploaded", name);
        res.send('Done! Uploading files')
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.send("No File selected !");
    res.end();
  };
})
```

Comment: Покажи `script`....  Выложи сюда... Нажми кнопку `править`  под вопросом и добавь

Comment: @Air добавил скрипт

Comment: `console.log(res.sendFile(__dirname +'../index.html'))` - эту строку добавь посмотри наглядно что будет в консоли

Comment: очевидна неверная сборка пути. Вместо прямой работы со строками лучше воспользоваться каким-нибудь [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Answer (score 1):

у тебя строка

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '../index.html');
```

ты пиши или абсолютный путь или относительный , а у тебя гибрид какой-то. и здесь у тебя и приблема.

```
 res.sendFile('../index.html');
```

например если у тебя файл   на  уровень выше - ../
если на том же - ./
на два уровня выше ../../   - и так далеее - это относительные пути.